# How to find the h2 database server is running or not from java code

Tags: h2

I need to find whether h2 database server is running or not from java code. I have tried `getStatus().isRunning(args)` methods but it always shows that **server is not running** even if the server is running. Below is my code:

```java
        Server server = Server.createTcpServer(args);

        // Find whether is server is on or not using "isRunning()" method
        if (server.isRunning(false)) {
            System.out.println("server is running");
        } else {
            System.out.println("server is not running");
        }

        // Find whether is server is on or not using "getStatus()" method

        String statVariable = server.getStatus();

        System.out.println("STATUS=" + statVariable);

        System.out.println("SERVER GONNA START");

        server.start();
```

Comment: What version of H2 are you using?

Comment: H2 version is 1.4.184

Comment: Can you provide some code please? How did you start H2 Server?

Answer (score 2):

perhaps you can send a request off to the port in question, assuming it is either WebServer or TCP server (the default ports being 8082 or 9092 respectively). You know that the call

drewmac:bin drewpierce$ **java -cp h2*.jar org.h2.tools.Server**

creates 3 servers and spits out something like:

TCP server running at `tcp://192.168.1.3:9092` (only local connections)

PG server running at `pg://192.168.1.3:5435` (only local connections)

Web Console server running at `http://192.168.1.3:8082` (only local connections)

then if you call the routine to show ports on your server with listening sockets
and my call would be 
drewmac:~ drewpierce$ **sudo lsof -i -P | grep -i "listen"**

java      81339     drewpierce   19u  IPv6 0xffffff800b782ac0      0t0  TCP *:**9092** (LISTEN)

java      81339     drewpierce   22u  IPv6 0xffffff800b781bc0      0t0  TCP *:**5435** (LISTEN)

java      81339     drewpierce   24u  IPv6 0xffffff8015620800      0t0  TCP *:**8082** (LISTEN)

now if you want to test the web server (http and html streams to port 80, 8082, whatever you make it, you can issue Chunk A. If you want to test the TCP server you can issue Chunk B.

Call Chunk A like **java GreetingClient localhost 8082**

or like **java GreetingClient ec2-1-2-3-4-amaz-aws-ec2.amazon.com 8082**

don't forget the 2 parameters in this test or it will barf

Chunk A:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
public class GreetingClient {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
// declaration section:
// mySocket: our client socket pretending to be a browser
// os: output stream
// is: input stream
        Socket mySocket = null;  
        DataOutputStream os = null;
        DataInputStream is = null;

        String serverName = args[0];
        int port = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
// Initialization section:
// btw make sure parameters are passed noting that this quick code is NOT
// Try to open input and output streams
        System.out.println("*1");
        try {
            mySocket = new Socket(serverName,port);
            os = new DataOutputStream(mySocket.getOutputStream());
            is = new DataInputStream(mySocket.getInputStream());
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            System.err.println("Don't know about host: hostname");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("Couldn't get I/O for the connection to: hostname");
        }
        System.out.println("*2");
// If everything has been initialized then we want to write some data
// to the socket we have opened a connection to on port 80, 8082, whatever 
// (what the server is listening on)
    if (mySocket != null && os != null && is != null) {
            try {
// pretend to be a browser and do a GET against a resource
        System.out.println("*3");
        os.writeBytes("GET /index.html HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n");    
        System.out.println("*4");
// wait for response from webserver, dump out response for sanity check
                String responseLine;
                while ((responseLine = is.readLine()) != null) {
                    System.out.println("Server: " + responseLine);
                    if (responseLine.indexOf("Ok") != -1) {
                      break;
                    }
                }
// clean up:
// close the output stream
// close the input stream
// close the socket
        System.out.println("*5");
        os.close();
                is.close();
                mySocket.close();   
            } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                System.err.println("Trying to connect to unknown host: " + e);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.err.println("IOException:  " + e);
            }
        }
        System.out.println("*6");
    }           
}
```

Chunk A output (for me at least):

```
*1
*2
*3
*4
Server: HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: Content-Type: text/html
Server: Cache-Control: no-cache
Server: Content-Length: 937
Server: 
Server: <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
Server: <!--
Server: Copyright 2004-2014 H2 Group. Multiple-Licensed under the MPL 2.0,
Server: and the EPL 1.0 (http://h2database.com/html/license.html).
Server: Initial Developer: H2 Group
Server: -->
Server: <html><head>
Server:     <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
Server:     <title>H2 Console</title>
Server:     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css" />
Server: <script type="text/javascript">
Server: location.href = 'login.jsp?jsessionid=f3d05d9b68f4c5407054628f096ffccb';
Server: </script>
Server: </head>
Server: <body style="margin: 20px;">
Server: 
Server: <h1>Welcome to H2</h1>
Server: <h2>No Javascript</h2>
Server: If you are not automatically redirected to the login page, then
Server: Javascript is currently disabled or your browser does not support Javascript.
Server: For this application to work, Javascript is essential.
Server: Please enable Javascript now, or use another web browser that supports it.
Server: 
Server: </body></html>
*5
*6
```

A few things, clearly this is H2 output. Chunk A source code could be whittled down to about 10 lines.

Chunk B (talk jdbc to TCP jdbc server)

```
//STEP 1. Import required packages
import java.sql.*;
import org.h2.Driver;

public class JdbcTrial {
   // JDBC driver name and database URL

   //static final String JDBC_DRIVER = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";  
   //static final String DB_URL = "jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1/test";

   static final String JDBC_DRIVER = "org.h2.Driver";  
   static final String DB_URL = "jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost/~/test";

   //  Database credentials
   static final String USER = "sa";
   static final String PASS = "";

   public static void main(String[] args) {
   Connection conn = null;
   Statement stmt = null;
   try{
      //STEP 2: Register JDBC driver
      System.out.println("***** 1");
      Class.forName(JDBC_DRIVER);
      System.out.println("***** 2");

      //STEP 3: Open a connection
      System.out.println("Connecting to database...");
      conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL,USER,PASS);

      //STEP 4: Execute a query
      System.out.println("Creating statement...");
      stmt = conn.createStatement();
      String sql;
      sql = "SELECT id, FirstName, LastName from people";
      ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);

      //STEP 5: Extract data from result set
      while(rs.next()){
         //Retrieve by column name
         int id  = rs.getInt("id");
         String first = rs.getString("FirstName");
         String last = rs.getString("LastName");

         //Display values
         System.out.print("ID: " + id);

         System.out.print(", First: " + first);
         System.out.println(", Last: " + last);
      }
      //STEP 6: Clean-up environment
      rs.close();
      stmt.close();
      conn.close();
   }catch(SQLException se){
      //Handle errors for JDBC
      se.printStackTrace();
   }catch(Exception e){
      //Handle errors for Class.forName
      e.printStackTrace();
   }finally{
      //finally block used to close resources
      try{
         if(stmt!=null)
            stmt.close();
      }catch(SQLException se2){
      }// nothing we can do
      try{
         if(conn!=null)
            conn.close();
      }catch(SQLException se){
         se.printStackTrace();
      }//end finally try
   }//end try
   System.out.println("Goodbye!");
}//end main
}//end FirstExample
```

Chunk B output:

```
drewmac:~ drewpierce$ java JdbcTrial
***** 1
***** 2
Connecting to database...
Creating statement...
ID: 1, First: joan, Last: london
ID: 2, First: Sgt., Last: Corholio
Goodbye!
```

worked fine against mysql, mariadb, and H2, just by messing with the jdbc_driver and db_url

You could just do socket connects and not issue off data retrieval calls and really prune it down.

As far as how to do this with the H2 getStatus, I have no clue. Good luck.

Comment: Maybe OP didn't value your extensive answer, but I do - thank you!